# Is it possible to use default arguments and a variable number of arguments in a single function?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, default-arguments

For example, something like this:

```
#include <cstdarg>

void my_function(int it=42, ...)
{
     /* va_list/start/arg/end code here */
}
```

What exactly does the above code mean in C++? It compiles fine in G++. Note, I can't imagine any scenario where this would be useful or even what it ought to do. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void my_function(int it=42, ...)
```

You said this function compiles fine with GCC, but you cannot make use of the default argument, you will have to pass argument for the so-called default parameter as well, to work with this function.

```
my_function("string", 98, 78, 99); //error
my_function(898, "string", 98, 78, 99); //ok, but the param 'it' becomes 898
```

Ask yourself:

Is the first argument `898` corresponds to the parameter `it` or it corresponds to the variadic parameter (and you intend to use the default value `42` for `it`)?

The compiler cannot know your intention!

BTW @Johannes pointed out a good point : you can simply call `my_function()` without passing any argument. That is the only instance I see when you can make use of the default argument.

---

Now if you change the position of the default parameter, something like this:

```
void f(..., int p = 10); //illegal
```

Then this is illegal in C++ to begin with.

Again, ask yourself : if it was allowed then you could call this as:

```
f(9879, 97897, 7897);
```

Is the last argument `7897` corresponds to the parameter `p` or it corresponds to the variadic parameter (and you intend to use the default value `10` for `p`)?

The compiler cannot know your intention in this case either.

Comment: Why is it not possibly to say `my_function();`? Also, you seem to say in the very last line that the declaration is valid, but in the first part of your answer say you cannot declare `my_function`. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I found no place in the C++03 standard that says the declaration in question is illegal.
And in C++11, it appears legal: an example to Section 8.3.6 "Default arguments" says `void g(int = 0, ...); // OK, ellipsis is not a parameter so it can follow a parameter with a default argument`. Your answer seems misleading to me.

Comment: @Alexey: If you gave me downvote, then its totally unjustified, since I **never** said *the declaration in question is illegal*. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz your answer says something different. How it looks to me: You first thought that `void f(int = 0, ...)` is illegal, and then tried with GCC, finding out that it accepts such. But you forgot to update your former text, that still reads "Since the default argument must start from the right-most parameter, so that is not possible ... Hence what you want is not possible.". I agree to @Alexey, it looks confusing.

Comment: No I did not downvote; why would I? But, Alessandro asked what this code mean, and you answered "No" and tried to explain why default arguments cannot be used with ellipsis. The answer of Charles is more on the point, I upvoted it.

Comment: @Johannes, and @Alexey : Yeah. I understand that now. That is why I changed the order of the my understanding and analysis.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's nothing technically wrong with this function declaration, although I wouldn't recommend this practice because it would be very easy to make a mistake which the compiler couldn't warn about when calling the function.

You can stop providing arguments at the first argument that has a default argument. If you let the default arguments take over then the variable argument list will, of course, be empty.

You can provide arguments beyond the named parameters so populating the variable argument list in which case none of the default arguments will be used.

As you indicate, whether there's a practical situation where this would actual be useful is another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
void my_function(int it=42, ...){ /* va_list/start/arg/end code here */}
```

Well that code ought to do exactly what it looks like. Fist parameter passed (if any) is parameter `it` and the rest is `...`. So if you pass no parameters then your `it` parameter is assigned default value (42) and `it` (that equals 42) is the only parameter passed into the function.

The code like this may be useful just like any other usage of `...`-terminated argument-list in similar situations (and the risk is of the same nature).

Example:

You may create function:

```
// DECLARATION:
// returns vector filled with items specified
std::vector<float> float_vector( size_t item_count = 0, ... /* floats */ );

// DEFINITION:
std::vector<float> float_vector( size_t item_count, ... )
{
    std::vector<float> vec;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, item_count);
    for( ; item_count > 0; --item_count )
    {
        vec.push_back( va_arg(ap,float) );
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return vec;
}
```

Obvoiusly `float_vector()` returns empty vector because it is equvalent to `float_vector(0)`. In all the other cases `float_vector` behaves like usual function with variable number of arguments.